# Parsing JSON with arrays and structures with Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion

I need to output the JSON result in HTML so that I can use it in Coldfusion. I am getting the data but I do not know how to parse the returned data so that I can use it. I am a newby so be easy on me. I don't know JSON at all and this is the first time I am trying to work work this.

```
    <cfset qpxFields = {
      "request": {
        "passengers": {
          "adultCount": "1"
        },
        "slice": [
          {
            "origin": "JNB",
            "destination": "MRU",
            "date": "2016-12-19"
          }
        ],
        "solutions": "1"
      }
    }/>

    <cfhttp url="https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=AIzaSyB0NN9WYmrkc2Ikq9TVGzzAD_gGoSBSbP4" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(qpxFields)#">
    </cfhttp>

    <cfset getResult = deserializeJSON(httpResp.filecontent)>
    <cfoutput>#httpResp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

The result I am getting when outputting the filecontent is the following:

```
{ "kind": "qpxExpress#tripsSearch", "trips": { "kind": "qpxexpress#tripOptions", "requestId": "ylROS8N2kR4vI8ktC0PQVj", "data": { "kind": "qpxexpress#data", "airport": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#airportData", "code": "JNB", "city": "JNB", "name": "Johannesburg O.R. Tambo International" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#airportData", "code": "MRU", "city": "MRU", "name": "Mauritius Sir S. Ramgoolam International" } ], "city": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#cityData", "code": "JNB", "name": "Johannesburg" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#cityData", "code": "MRU", "name": "Mauritius" } ], "aircraft": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#aircraftData", "code": "343", "name": "Airbus A340" } ], "tax": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxData", "id": "EV_001", "name": "South Africa Passenger Safety Charge" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxData", "id": "YQ_F", "name": "MK YQ surcharge" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxData", "id": "YR_I", "name": "MK YR surcharge" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxData", "id": "ZA_001", "name": "South Africa Passenger Service Charge" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxData", "id": "UM_001", "name": "South Africa Asc Charge" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxData", "id": "WC_001", "name": "South Africa Air Passenger Tax" } ], "carrier": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#carrierData", "code": "MK", "name": "AIR MAURITIUS LTD" } ] }, "tripOption": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#tripOption", "saleTotal": "ZAR5398.23", "id": "bGXAC5TFGRFO06xEFBzMaA001", "slice": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInfo", "duration": 240, "segment": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#segmentInfo", "duration": 240, "flight": { "carrier": "MK", "number": "852" }, "id": "GB3DFc4zHshnkF7H", "cabin": "COACH", "bookingCode": "T", "bookingCodeCount": 9, "marriedSegmentGroup": "0", "leg": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#legInfo", "id": "LwsDBsjHUFZrYe5Y", "aircraft": "343", "arrivalTime": "2016-12-19T19:35+04:00", "departureTime": "2016-12-19T13:35+02:00", "origin": "JNB", "destination": "MRU", "originTerminal": "B", "duration": 240, "mileage": 1904, "meal": "Meal" } ] } ] } ], "pricing": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#pricingInfo", "fare": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#fareInfo", "id": "AdGb1tIdX7T9uIyT9qTU9OFHTXhaVL0C0ojKd7a7use6", "carrier": "MK", "origin": "JNB", "destination": "MRU", "basisCode": "TAANOWMU" } ], "segmentPricing": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#segmentPricing", "fareId": "AdGb1tIdX7T9uIyT9qTU9OFHTXhaVL0C0ojKd7a7use6", "segmentId": "GB3DFc4zHshnkF7H" } ], "baseFareTotal": "ZAR3690.00", "saleFareTotal": "ZAR3690.00", "saleTaxTotal": "ZAR1708.23", "saleTotal": "ZAR5398.23", "passengers": { "kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts", "adultCount": 1 }, "tax": [ { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxInfo", "id": "ZA_001", "chargeType": "GOVERNMENT", "code": "ZA", "country": "ZA", "salePrice": "ZAR346.00" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxInfo", "id": "EV_001", "chargeType": "GOVERNMENT", "code": "EV", "country": "ZA", "salePrice": "ZAR20.23" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxInfo", "id": "UM_001", "chargeType": "GOVERNMENT", "code": "UM", "country": "ZA", "salePrice": "ZAR24.00" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxInfo", "id": "WC_001", "chargeType": "GOVERNMENT", "code": "WC", "country": "ZA", "salePrice": "ZAR190.00" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxInfo", "id": "YQ_F", "chargeType": "CARRIER_SURCHARGE", "code": "YQ", "salePrice": "ZAR1090.00" }, { "kind": "qpxexpress#taxInfo", "id": "YR_I", "chargeType": "CARRIER_SURCHARGE", "code": "YR", "salePrice": "ZAR38.00" } ], "fareCalculation": "JNB MK MRU 260.69TAANOWMU NUC 260.69 END ROE 14.15458 FARE ZAR 3690.00 XT 20.23EV 24.00UM 190.00WC 346.00ZA 1090.00YQ 38.00YR", "latestTicketingTime": "2016-12-19T06:34-05:00", "ptc": "ADT", "refundable": true } ] } ] } }
```

I am using CF 10.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to deal with the HTTP response (`httpResp.filecontent`) look at your deserialized content (`getResult`).  You cannot simply output that variable as ColdFusion creates a structure from the JSON data.

Dump out your deserialzed JSON like this:

```
<cfdump var="#getResult#">
```

Looking at that output you will see how ColdFusion has already parsed all of the information for you. You are going to have some structure values and some array values. You will need to use appropriate methods (looping over an array for example) to extract each individual piece of data.

*Reply to your comment*

Looping in ColdFusion is well documented. To get you started you can look at the Adobe documentation itself - [cfloop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fe2.html).  The documentation on that page shows how to link over arrays, structures, etc.

Another good reference is [Learn CF In a Week - looping](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Looping/).

Comment: Yes, I understand that I will need to use appropriate methods. That's the problem. I do not know how to loop over arrays and structures etc in order to extract the data to be usable. I can't find understandable documentation about that either. Basically that is what I need help with. How do I extract the data by looping and being able to insert into a table for example.

Comment: I responded to you in the answer above. Looping in ColdFusion is documented extensively on the internet. I gave you a couple of examples to get you started.

Comment: I wrote up detailed documentation on how to loop through various data objects with any version of ColdFusion: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/coldfusion/3035/cfloop-how-to#t=201611111534280973313

Answer (score 0):

Looping works when you have to traverse one-dimensional or two-dimensional structs or arrays. When the data combines structs and arrays in 3 or more dimensions, as in this particular problem, then looping is often insufficient as a solution. The complexity will certainly overwhelm most beginners.

A good solution is to play dumb. Start with the result, the structure getResult. Do a dump, as suggested by others earlier. Then simply *run through it by eye* and *drill down to the values*.

The list of values is:

```
getResult.kind

getResult.trips.data.aircraft[1].code
getResult.trips.data.aircraft[1].kind
getResult.trips.data.aircraft[1].name
getResult.trips.data.airport[1].city
getResult.trips.data.airport[1].code
getResult.trips.data.airport[1].kind
getResult.trips.data.airport[1].name
getResult.trips.data.airport[2].city
getResult.trips.data.airport[2].code
getResult.trips.data.airport[2].kind
getResult.trips.data.airport[2].name
getResult.trips.data.carrier[1].code
getResult.trips.data.carrier[1].kind
getResult.trips.data.carrier[1].name
getResult.trips.data.city[1].code
getResult.trips.data.city[1].kind
getResult.trips.data.city[1].name
getResult.trips.data.city[2].code
getResult.trips.data.city[2].kind
getResult.trips.data.city[2].name
getResult.trips.data.kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[1].id
getResult.trips.data.tax[1].kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[1].name
getResult.trips.data.tax[2].id
getResult.trips.data.tax[2].kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[2].name
getResult.trips.data.tax[3].id
getResult.trips.data.tax[3].kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[3].name
getResult.trips.data.tax[4].id
getResult.trips.data.tax[4].kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[4].name
getResult.trips.data.tax[5].id
getResult.trips.data.tax[5].kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[5].name
getResult.trips.data.tax[6].id
getResult.trips.data.tax[6].kind
getResult.trips.data.tax[6].name

getResult.trips.kind
getResult.trips.requestId

getResult.trips.tripOption[1].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].kind 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].saletotal 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].basefareTotal 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fare[1].basiscode
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fare[1].carrier
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fare[1].destination
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fare[1].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fare[1].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fare[1].origin
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].fareCalculation
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].latestTicketingTime
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].passengers.adultCount
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].passengers.kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].ptc
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].refundable
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].saleFareTotal
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].saletaxTotal
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].saleTotal
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].segmentPricing[1].fareId
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].segmentPricing[1].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].segmentPricing[1].segmentId
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[1].chargeType
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[1].code
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[1].country
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[1].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[1].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[1].salePrice
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[2].chargeType
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[2].code
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[2].country
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[2].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[2].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[2].salePrice
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[3].chargeType
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[3].code
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[3].country
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[3].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[3].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[3].salePrice
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[4].chargeType
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[4].code
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[4].country
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[4].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[4].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[4].salePrice
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[5].chargeType
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[5].code
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[5].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[5].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[5].salePrice
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[6].chargeType
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[6].code
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[6].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[6].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].pricing[1].tax[6].salePrice
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].saletotal 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].duration
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].bookingCode
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].bookingCodeCount 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].cabin 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].duration 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].flight.carrier 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].flight.number 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].id 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].kind 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].aircraft
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].arrivalTime
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].departureTime
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].destination
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].duration
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].id
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].kind
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].meal
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].mileage
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].origin
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].leg[1].originTerminal 
getResult.trips.tripOption[1].slice[1].segment[1].marriedSegmentGroup
```