# Trying to parse JSON with Coldfusion and running into structural problems

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfml

I apologize as I am new to JSON. Usually have been using XML for all these years. I'm trying to grab structs from a feed from the NWS.

So for example, here is the source: https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active?zone=OHC051

So I am setting using a cfset to grab a long feed. But here is an example of the beginning of it:

```
<cfset weather = '{
    "@context": [
        "https://geojson.org/geojson-ld/geojson-context.jsonld",
        {
            "version": "1.1",
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology",
            "vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology"
        }
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id":     "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.f70076597ffcf16333ee886fe424c7cc5e23cb1e.001.1",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": null,
        "properties": {
            "@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.f70076597ffcf16333ee886fe424c7cc5e23cb1e.001.1",
            "@type": "wx:Alert",
            "id": "urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.f70076597ffcf16333ee886fe424c7cc5e23cb1e.001.1",
            "areaDesc": "Lagrange; Steuben; Noble; De Kalb; Whitley; Allen; Huntington; Wells; Adams; St. Joseph; Branch; Hillsdale; Williams; Fulton; Defiance; Henry; Paulding; Putnam; Van Wert",
            "geocode": {
                "SAME": [
                    "018087",
                    "018151",
                    "018113",
                    "018033",
                    "018183",
                    "018003",
                    "018069",
                    "018179",
                    "018001",
                    "026149",
                    "026023",
                    "026059",
                    "039171",
                    "039051",
                    "039039",
                    "039069",
                    "039125",
                    "039137",
                    "039161"
                ],
                "UGC": [
                    "INZ006",
                    "INZ007",
                    "INZ008",
                    "INZ009",
                    "INZ017",
                    "INZ018",
                    "INZ025",
                    "INZ026",
                    "INZ027",
                    "MIZ079",
                    "MIZ080",
                    "MIZ081",
                    "OHZ001",
                    "OHZ002",
                    "OHZ004",
                    "OHZ005",
                    "OHZ015",
                    "OHZ016",
                    "OHZ024"
                ]
            },
            "affectedZones": [
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ006",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ007",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ008",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ009",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ017",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ018",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ025",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ026",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/INZ027",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/MIZ079",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/MIZ080",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/MIZ081",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ001",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ002",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ004",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ005",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ015",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ016",
                "https://api.weather.gov/zones/forecast/OHZ024"
            ],
            "references": [],
            "sent": "2024-01-30T21:32:00-05:00",
            "effective": "2024-01-30T21:32:00-05:00",
            "onset": "2024-01-30T21:32:00-05:00",
            "expires": "2024-01-31T05:45:00-05:00",
            "ends": "2024-01-31T09:00:00-05:00",
            "status": "Actual",
            "messageType": "Alert",
            "category": "Met",
            "severity": "Moderate",
            "certainty": "Likely",
            "urgency": "Expected",
            "event": "Dense Fog Advisory",
            "sender": "w-nws.webmaster@noaa.gov",
            "senderName": "NWS Northern Indiana",
            "headline": "Dense Fog Advisory issued January 30 at 9:32PM EST until January 31 at 9:00AM EST by NWS Northern Indiana",
            "description": "* WHAT...Visibility one quarter to one half mile in dense fog.\n\n* WHERE...Portions of northern Indiana, southwest Michigan and\nnorthwest Ohio.\n\n* WHEN...Until 9 AM EST Wednesday.\n\n* IMPACTS...Hazardous driving conditions due to low visibility.",
            "instruction": "If driving, slow down, use your headlights, and leave plenty of\ndistance ahead of you.",
            "response": "Execute",
            "parameters": {
                "AWIPSidentifier": [
                    "NPWIWX"
                ],
                "WMOidentifier": [
                    "WWUS73 KIWX 310232"
                ],
                "NWSheadline": [
                    "DENSE FOG ADVISORY IN EFFECT UNTIL 9 AM EST WEDNESDAY"
                ],
                "BLOCKCHANNEL": [
                    "EAS",
                    "NWEM",
                    "CMAS"
                ],
                "VTEC": [
                    "/O.NEW.KIWX.FG.Y.0003.240131T0232Z-240131T1400Z/"
                ],
                "eventEndingTime": [
                    "2024-01-31T14:00:00+00:00"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.2b7ae562fae2efebc0268af8a1e8209d22031ef5.005.1",
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -84.439999999999998,
                        41.299999999999997
                    ],
                    [
                        -84.4599999,
                        41.489999999999995
                    ],
                    [
                        -84.390000000000001,
                        41.589999999999996
                    ],
                    [
                        -84.290000000000006,
                        41.589999999999996
                    ],
                    [
                        -84.38000000000001,
                        41.299999999999997
                    ],
                    [
                        -84.439999999999998,
                        41.299999999999997
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
```

At the end I am trying to perform a writeout similar to the following:

```
<cfscript>
  record=deserializeJSON(#weather#);
  writeOutput(record.type.features.type & " ");
</cfscript>
```

One of the biggest problems I have is trying to identify the vars. So for example... I have been get vars like the following: areaDesc, effective, event and description.

But for the life of me I cannot get it to work. Wait I misspoke... I was able to get writeOutput(record.type & " "); to work and display "FeatureCollection" but that is it.

Not looking for someone to do my work.... but just have been at this for a long time and an hitting a wall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON with arrays and structures with Coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549458/parsing-json-with-arrays-and-structures-with-coldfusion)

Comment: Use writeDump(var=record); to view the data that is deserialized

Comment: This is not a question about JSON, it's a question about accessing struct/array values. That the source of the data was JSON becomes irrelevant as soon as you call `deserializeJson`: after that it's a struct. You say you accessed `record.type` and got `FeatureCollection`... well... yeah: that's the value of that element. This is probably a matter of reading the docs a bit: https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-arrays-and-structures/about-structures.html